# Azure Blob Storage - Uploading from Upload Control .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an issue with uploading files from a web application to Azure Blob Storage. Everything works perfectly in development mode, however when I publish I am unable to upload the files. How do I access the file to upload please? Below is the code I have which works in development just not in production:

aspx page:

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelUpload">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="file" id="myfile" multiple="multiple" name="myfile" runat="server" />
     </div> <br />
     <asp:Button ID="Button_Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload New Images" OnClick="Click_UploadImages" CssClass="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1 w-100" />
                <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Span1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Click_UploadImages(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
        CloudStorageAccount sa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
        CloudBlobClient bc = sa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = bc.GetContainerReference(destContainer);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
            try
            {
                if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob b = container.GetBlockBlobReference(product_id + "-" + i + Path.GetExtension(userPostedFile.FileName));
                    //b.UploadFromFile(userPostedFile.FileName);
                    using (var fs = File.Open(userPostedFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        b.UploadFromStream(fs);
                    }

                    //Image Record to SQL After BLOB Upload
                    TraceBlobImageUsingSQL T = new TraceBlobImageUsingSQL();
                    T.ImageSQLEntry(product_id, i, "productimages", b.Name, userPostedFile.ContentLength, Path.GetExtension(userPostedFile.FileName), Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Span1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;
            }
        }
        RenderHTMLPanelData(Request.QueryString["ProductID"]);
    }
```

Comment: could u please explain this => `I am unable to upload the files`

Comment: did u face any error or exception?

Comment: When I select a file to upload and press the upload button I catch this error: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\selectedfile.jpg'. I have tried changing the path, using Server.MapPath("~") etc but cannot get it to work once published.

Comment: try to add breakpoint here => `HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;` and watch is there any file exist in  `uploadedFiles`?

Comment: yes, files exist at the breakpoint. while debugging it works flawlessly, it is only when I publish that it stops working and fails to upload the files, Somehow I seem to be using the full path which while debugging I have access to. Once published it works as Client-> Server so I cannot obtain the full file path to upload from the client device. as an example while debugging if I write out the "userPostedFile.FileName" I get: C:\Users\xxx\filename.jpg however once published the "userPostedFile.FileName" becomes filename.jpg loosing the path.

Comment: Instead of opening FileStream, try to directly read file contents as stream: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream?view=netframework-4.7.2. Something like: `using (var stream = userPostedFile.InpuStream)
                    {
                        b.UploadFromStream(stream);
                    }`

Comment: add this attribute to your form tag => `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Gaurav Mantri - Your answer works flawlessly, a simply change to access the stream directly and the file is uploaded even when published. Thank you so much. I will vote as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Cool. I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpPostedFile exposes [`InputStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) property that lets you read the contents directly as stream. Use that instead of opening up a file stream:

```
                using (var stream = userPostedFile.InpuStream)
                {
                    b.UploadFromStream(stream);
                }
```